# std::vector<std::mutex> stuck with optimization

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, mutex

I wrote a program which uses massive parallel execution. I am working with an Array of objects and an Array of mutexes for synchronization. My code Looks something like this:

```
std::vector<MyObject> objects;
std::vector<std::mutex> mutexes;

void work(int data)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i)
    {
        //Check if data Needs to be processed for objects[i]
        if(dontNeedToProcess)continue;

        mutexes[i].lock();
        //Work with data for objects[i]
        mutexes[i].unlock();
    }
}
```

The function "work" is called by multiple threads with different data. After some hours (sometimes even days) the program is stuck. When I run it with gdb I can see that the program hangs while locking the mutex.

The Problem is now that I compiled the progrem with optimization (-O2) and the mutexes and "i" are optimized out.

Is it possible that the optimization causes this behavior when using an Array of mutexes?

Edit:
All the threads are at the same Position. The Backtrace Looks like the following:

```
#0  0xb7779d3c in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb67ff672 in __lll_lock_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/lowlevellock.S:144
#2  0xb67fb1c2 in _L_lock_920 ()
   from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
#3  0xb67fb043 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x9de56530)
    at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:114
#4  0xb69043c4 in pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x9de56530) at forward.c:192
#5  0xb72754f3 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasan.so.1
#6  0x0809ac85 in __gthread_mutex_lock (__mutex=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/gthr-default.h:748
#7  lock (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:135
...
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between them? i.e. they are the same size? Why dont you put them in a common struct?

Comment: Yes I am sure that they have the same size. Saving them in the same structure is a good idea, I will try that.

Comment: Are the *vectors* `objects` or `mutexes` modified concurrently with function `work()`? How is `if(dontNeedToProcess)` performed? Can it (or the work on the data) throw exceptions?

Comment: You should use std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexes[i]); instead of locking and unlocking the mutex manually.

Comment: The objects itself are modified, the vector not. dontNeedToProcess Doesn't Access the object or the mutex. About the exceptions: I ran gdb with catching exceptions and it didn't catch any

Comment: If it hangs it means that another thread has it, can you go thread by thread and see what they are currently doing? How many threads are there?

Comment: Currently there are 4 threads. They are all at the same Position. Please look at my edited post.

Comment: Sounds like they are all trying to process the same value of `i`. So we really need to know more about `if(dontNeedToProcess)`.

Comment: Either that or sometimes a *mutex* is not getting unlocked, `lock_guard` should fix that

Comment: dontNeedToProcess doesn't touch the objects. So this can't be the cause. So it really must be that I don't unlock the mutex (even if I don't think so). I will try the lock_guard then.

Comment: To Summarize: So you are saying that the optimized mutex/vector combination can't be the cause of the Problem, right?

Comment: Compile with `-O0` and see for yourself :) Usually, you can get more useful information from gdb when optimization is disabled, like inspecting variables and such

Comment: If dontNeedToProcess doesn't touch the object you're getting to a state where that's false for all threads

Comment: If "//Work with data for objects[i]" has *any* form of a `continue` or a `break` to prematurely leave the loop, that is a recipe for leaving your mutex locked. Use a scope-guarded latch on that mutex instead as hello_world suggested.